# Selecting every n'th index using modulo in geometry nodes

Tags: mathematics, geometry-nodes

How can I go about selecting every **n'th** index using modulo in geometry nodes.

Example: I have an index range of 0-35 and would like to select every **9th index** so I can place an icosphere on it, which math node/s am I missing? Should I be using modulo or should I use something else?

[image: img1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if the modulo result is zero with the Compare node.

[image: Geometry nodes modulo selection]