# Selecting every n'th index between the numerical index ranges of b and c using modulo in geometry nodes

Tags: mathematics, geometry-nodes

This question is similar to [Selecting every n'th index using modulo in geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263063/selecting-every-nth-index-using-modulo-in-geometry-nodes/263066#263066) but with an added range option.

I can select every n'th number thanks to [Hulifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/127847/hulifier)

[image: img1]

I'm trying to select every n'th index, but only choose from the selected indexes between the ranges of `b` and `c` using modulo in geometry nodes.

My logic doesn't seem to work for selecting every n'th index between the numerical index ranges `b` and `c` using modulo.  I checked the output with the viewer (it seems to select the index range I want but the modulo doesn't seem to be executing the way I thought.  I should have only 3 icospheres showing up.)

[image: img2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to take modulo from index, not from boolean. Modulo is the rest of a division, so it makes no sense to get a modulo value from a boolean (which is just 0 and 1).
you might want to add an add note before your modulo so that it starts with 0 and not an arbitrary value.

this should work:

[image]

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  But is it possible to choose from a specified index range?  It's like I need another Node that does an `AND` operation but for indexes instead of booleans.

Comment: but you did this already perfectly in your node tree! you connected "and" to the "lower" and "greater" - that's the right way! So i don't understand what you mean now?

Comment: just connect index to "modulo value" and the "and" result boolean to the last "and" boolean

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Thanks that did it.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: if you want a "constant" start value (e.g. it start always with false) you can add a "start index modulo 3" expression to your index before doing your modulo and then add a constant value (1, 2,3 however you want the start to be like) so that you will always have a start with e.g. true, false, false. else the start of your selection will be arbitrary...only if you want ;)

Comment: @Chris given the min max are integer inputs it might be best to add and subtract a decimal offset to have them inclusive (most specifically evaluating the 0 index) and my interpretation was that the modulo should start at the min value so subtract min from index going into modulo but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ratt: yeah...there are several ways to do so ;)

Comment: Thanks! I add that to the Node tree.